# Circular import Django and im lost ... :(

Tags: django

I got my services.py where i am trying to make api connections based on some tables in models(fex user):

```
import requests
import json
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import UserProfile,House
```

have a function here that call 2 database queries to get more info to connect towards the API

and my models.py contains:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from .services import *
connectApi() -> function in services.py
```

Comment: Well, yes, services.py imports models.py and models.py imports services.py, that's a circular import that's not resolvable. One of them needs to do the import inside a function only, not at the module level. Preferably they shouldn't have a circular relationship in the first place, i.e. models should probably not import services.

Comment: problem solved and another lesson learned ! thanks !

Answer (score 0):

so the solution is

```
def connectApi():
from .models import ....
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Remember to provide an explanation of your solution & make sure to format the code correctly.